# jenkins plugin is not loaded

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to write a plugin for jenkins called `team-quotes`. It is based on chuck norris plugin.
when I try to run local jenkins on go the the main page I get `404`.
In the output of jenkins the are some warnings:

`INFO: Started initialization

Jul 17, 2014 3:09:53 PM hudson.PluginManager$1$3$1 isDuplicate

INFO: Ignoring C:\Users\oshai\Documents\GitHub\team-quotes-plugin\.\work\plugins\teamquotes.hpl because C:\Users\oshai\Documents\GitHub\team-quotes-plugin\.\work\plugins\teamquotes.hpl is already loaded`

the plugin is in github:
https://github.com/oshai/team-quotes-plugin

I suspect when I renamed the plugin I forgot a place, but I cant find such.

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the url in the [tutorial](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+tutorial) is not correct. it should be: `http://localhost:8080/`
and not: `http://localhost:8080/jenkins`